# Where is wifi username or password stored in windows-7

Tags: windows, windows-7, wireless-networking

Anyone knows how and where the WiFi passwords are stored in windows-7. i want to saving and restoring when if you forget your username or password.

Comment: hopefully it is stored encrypted...

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used NirSoft's [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) to get my saved wifi passwords.  It's free and works well.  Be sure you download the correct version (32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks, select network profile from the list, right-click > choose Properties > switch to Security Tab > check the "Show characters" check-box.